# Docker Compose automatically setting links

Tags: docker-compose

Docker compose seems to be automatically setting links in hosts files when I start things up:

```
root@47f648654cc9:/opt/mio# cat /etc/hosts
172.17.1.54     47f648654cc9
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
172.17.1.54     mio-events-service.bridge
172.17.1.52     mongodb.bridge
172.17.1.54     mio-events-service
172.17.1.52     mongodb
172.17.1.53     consul
172.17.1.53     consul.bridge
172.17.1.55     registrator
172.17.1.55     registrator.bridge
172.17.1.56     kv-registration
172.17.1.56     kv-registration.bridge
172.17.1.57     rabbitmq
172.17.1.57     rabbitmq.bridge
```

i.e. I don't have to supply "links:" elements in docker-compose.yml to get links between containers. This seems to be contradictory to the documentation. Any ideas why it's doing this?

Thanks

Nick

**UPDATE**

Here's my compose file

```
consul:
  image: registry.systems.com/consuld
  container_name: consul
  ports:
    - "8400:8400"
    - "8500:8500"
    - "53:8600/udp"
  environment:
    - IP=192.168.99.100
  hostname: dockermachine

registrator:
  image: gliderlabs/registrator:latest
  container_name: registrator
  command: consul://consul:8500
  volumes:
    - "/var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock"
  links:
    - consul

kv-registration:
  image: registry.systems.com/nativ/consul-local-kv-registration
  container_name: kv-registration
  links:
    - consul

rabbitmq:
  image: rabbitmq
  container_name: rabbitmq
  ports:
    - 4369:4369
    - 5672:5672
    - 15672:15672
    - 25672:25672

mongodb:
  image: mongo
  container_name: mongodb
  ports:
    - 27017:27017
    - 28017:28017

mio-events-service:
  image: registry.systems.com/mio-events-service:1.0.190
  container_name: mio-events-service
  ports:
    - 18113:18113
  extra_hosts:
   - "dockermachine:192.168.99.100"
```

Comment: what is you `docker-compose.yml` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're using `--x-networking` which replaces links, and adds these host entries for every container on the same network.

See http://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Comment: Thanks for the information. We're not setting that switch explicitly, but perhaps it's set by default somehow on our version